# interfacing hardware with diff_drive_controller

Tags: ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am building a differential drive robot and I want to exploit the power of the diff_drive_controller

but I have faced a couple of problems to interface my hardware to the controller I am using a tiva c launchpad as my embedded board but the real problem is, where can I get the velocity output of each wheel from the controller then I can transfer it with the appropriate method to the motors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300686/interfacing-hardware-with-diff_drive_controller/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're in luck as someone has addressed it for you: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_tivac

Go through the info and ask again if you get stuck,

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-08-16**:
Yup I know about this rosserial_tivac
but if you can help me with getting the output of the controller I couldn't understand how can I get the velocity command output there is no such topic published for each wheel so I can transfer it to the tivac

I appreciate your time and help

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-08-16**:
after a good research I have found that I should write a hardware_interface in order to take the cmd values for each wheel and give feedback of each one as well then I can expose these values to a topic to use rosserial in order to transfer it to the tivac, please correct me if I am wrong